# Is there a good reason to prevent users from using cron/at?

Tags: cron, scheduling

At work on our linux servers, I have a standard non root account.

Unfortunately the account does not have permissions to `crontab` or `at`.

Is there a good reason to block these commands?

I can write a script that uses sleep to do the stuff I want to schedule but I would rather do it in either `cron` or `at`.

Comment: Why are people marking this question as too broad? I can't imagine a more specific way of phrasing this and it's a valid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It slightly simplifies system administration, because users can be locked out by using `/etc/nologin` and `kill`, without having to worry about processes coming back through cron or at.

It shouldn't be a big problem if you can run your own cron daemon.

Comment: It would be an issue if the system is rebooted and the OP isn't notified.

Comment: @Bratchley system reboot was indeed my primary concern.